# Express a linear form that vanishes on the kernel of a linear map as a composition of the linear map and another form

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm working on a proof in the course of which I'd like to make the following claim:

If $A:X\rightarrow Y$ is a surjective continuous linear map between two Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$, and $x^*\in X^*$ is a continuous linear form that vanishes on the kernel of $A$ (i.e., $x^*(x)=0, \forall x\in\mathrm{ker}A$), then there exists a $y^*\in Y^*$ ($Y^*$ being the topological dual of $Y$) such that $x^*=y^*\circ A$.

My first thought has been, of course, to work in $X\diagup\mathrm{ker}A$. However, natural as this step may be, I still don't see the next step.

I'd appreciate any help with proving (or disproving) this claim.

Comment: Define $y^*(Ax)=x^*(x)$. Your hypotheses imply this is a well-defined function on $Y$. It is also linear. Since $A$ is onto, you can use the open mapping theorem to show it is bounded.

Comment: Perhaps first show: there is a $K>0$ so that to each $y\in A(X)$ there is an $x\in X$ with $y=Ax$ and $\Vert x\Vert\le K\Vert y\Vert$.

Comment: @DavidMitra -- Thank you very much for the hints.